# Did I do this correctly - Call an action from controller with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, link-to

Please excuse the simplicity and length of this, but I have a little test app that has a users table, with name, email, and salary attributes. I created a mailer that will send out a report of this data to a specific user at my discretion, in other words, when I click a button. My button is created using link_to, and calls an action in my main users_controller, which then calls the mailer action. (I hope that just made sense). It looks like the following and is working just as I hoped; I'm just looking to know if this is the right way to do something like this:

In my users_controller (created by the scaffold generator):

```
def sendemail  
@user = User.find(params[:id])  
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver  
redirect_to user_path(@user)  
flash[:notice] = 'Email has been sent!'  
end
```

In the user_mailer.rb file:

```
def welcome_email(user)
@user = user
@url  = "http://example.com/login"
mail(:to => user.email,
     :subject => "Welcome to My Awesome Site")
end
```

In the User's show.html.erb page, this is how the email gets sent:

```
<%= link_to "Send Email", sendemail_user_path(@user) %>
```

In my routes.rb file, so that everything executes properly (which it does):

```
resources :users do 
member do 
get 'sendemail'
end
```

So, having said all this, it works just like it should. I click on the user's show.html.erb page where I would have the data and charts that I want to eventually display, and at my discretion, I can kick out an email to that user with this data, or whatever I put in the mailer.html.erb file. When it is sent, it flashes the message I specified in the controller, and leaves me on that page, just as I specified; so it's working. I just want to know, is this the right and most ruby/railsy way to do things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code looks very similar to the [Rails Guides Action Mailer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) example, so suffice it to say you are creating railsy code.

Also, if your application evolved into a much grander scale you would want to consider delivering emails via a background job to avoid email deliveries from blocking the current thread.

Otherwise the code looks great. Of course, you would most likely send an email after doing something successful in a controller, rather than have a dedicated action for emailing directly. For instance, you might have a `welcome` action that sends an email on a successful user record save.

Comment: Thanks for the response and feedback. Can you explain what you mean by this: "consider delivering emails via a background job to avoid email deliveries from blocking the current thread"

Comment: @FattRyan - Sure thing. So in this simple case it's not really necessary, but if you were trying to send an email for multiple users in an array from the controller, the controller method would block until all of those emails were sent out. Instead of having your user wait around for the Action Mailer to finish sending these emails, you would want to send those emails out in the background and have the controller return a view to the user ASAP. My point is about application responsiveness for the user. Also if an email fails would you want the controller to fail (thus returning the view fails)

Comment: Or would you want to handle errors in the background, and if any appear, resend the email out in the background? It's generally best to keep long operations out of the main code path if at all possible. In the case of emails its generally okay to send them out behind the scenes and move along with getting any view data back to the user right away. Does that clear it up?

Comment: yes, that does help quite a bit, thanks for clarifying, makes total sense.